# 'NSMenu' may not respond to 'initWithTitle:action:keyEquivalent:'

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I try to add an option to my app's menu with the following code:

```
NSMenuItem *myNewMenuItem = [[[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"MenuOption1" action:@selector(myNewMenuItemMethod) keyEquivalent:@"j"] autorelease];

[myMenu addItem:myNewMenuItem];
```

While compiling I get the title's warning, which shows up in the console and my app will not run at all. Does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting a warning is that you're trying to assign a "`NSMenu`" object to something you've declared as a "`NSMenuItem`".

Which is not the same thing.  NSMenu objects *use* NSMenuItems to define the items they display.

Use [`[[NSMenuItem alloc] initWIthTitle: action: keyEquivalent:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenuItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMenuItem/initWithTitle%3aaction%3akeyEquivalent%3a)